# Fourier and differentiation operators

Tags: derivatives, fourier-analysis

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in the Schwartz class, define $$Tf(y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$

We can show that $T^2f(y)=f(-y)$, and $T^4f(y)=f(y)$. Also, define $$Af(y)=yf(y)+\dfrac{d}{dy}f(y)$$ For what value of $a$ is  $TA=aAT$?

Using $T^4Af(y)=Af(y)$, I can get $$a^4AT^4f(y)=a^4Af(y)=Af(y)$$ so $a^4=1$, so $a=\pm 1,\pm i$. But it doesn't really tell which values of $a$ work.

What can I do to identify which values of $a$ work?

Comment: Write down the integral for $T(Af)$. Note that $xf(x)e^{-ixy} = i\frac{d}{dy}(f(x)e^{-ixy})$. Integrate $f'(x)e^{-ixy}$ by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that some value of $a$ must work, then you can plug in a function $f$ that is simple, for example, $f\equiv1$ or something like that, to get information on the value of the constant $a$.